# Form is submitted twice on IE only

Tags: forms, double-submit-prevention

I have a jsp login form page,which uses stripes:submit button to call ActionBean method as well as an OnClick() javascript function on the stripes:submit button to submit the login form. In this scenario, the IE8 browser sends the request twice. It works fine for other browsers like FF and Chrome.Is there any way to prevent it.

Thanks in advance for yours assistance.

Regards,

NM

Comment: I'd post at least the code with the form, the submit button and the javascript logic if you expect any kind of help.